# How to Change User Authentication Banner Message?

Tags: ssh

I have created a new user with -e option to make it active for just 30 days. This user do ssh tunnel using Bitvise SSH Client for Windows. When the user account has expired bitvise shows a User Authentication Banner says "Your account has expired, Please contact your system administrator".The bitvise log says "User authentication banner received from the server". So i think this message come from server side.

How to change this message ?  I am using debian 6.

[image: User Authentication Banner]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messaging can be controlled through the `Banner` and `Match` commands in the `sshd_config` file. You can create `Match` sections which can override the global settings with custom ones based on the `Match`. So you could `Match` specific users and have different Banners for them vs. everyone else.

```
Match Group admins Address 1.2.3.0/24 
Banner /etc/ssh/someothermsgfile.txt
```

Comment: What is the content of the someothermsgfile.txt if i want to create expired banner ? or there is a manual about this ?

Comment: It's covered in the man page for `sshd_config`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also enter "none" for the Banner, and nothing will be displayed.